# Python Error: importlib.machinery

Tags: python

```
from importlib.machinery import EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
```

ImportError: No module named machinery

---

Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1

I'm currently installing GeoNode on Windows, that's the environment I have to make it work for now.
And with many hiccups, I got stuck with the above error.
I can't find to install machinery package on Web.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: What version of Python are you running? `importlib` was added in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3:

```
Python 3.3.1
>>> from importlib.machinery import EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
>>>
```

Python 2:

```
Python 2.7.4 
>>> from importlib.machinery import EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named machinery
>>>
```